# can't start media recorder in javascript getting unkown error

Tags: javascript, electron, web-mediarecorder

I am using media stream recorder to use with ffmpeg in electron js then when stopping then starting again the record i am getting
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn0wY.png)

i am starting record with timeslice = 0

```js
const sourcesMediaStream = new MediaStream()
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: { deviceId: { exact: "default" } } }).then(stream => {
    sourcesMediaStream.addTrack(stream.getAudioTracks()[0])
})
videoStream = canvas.captureStream(15).getVideoTracks()[0]
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(sourcesMediaStream, {
    audioBitsPerSecond: 128000,
    videoBitsPerSecond: 2500000,
})
btn.addEventListner("click", () => {
  if (!streaming) {
    recorder.start(0)
  } else {
    recorder.stop()
  }
})

recorder.ondataavailable = async function (e) {
    ipcRenderer.send("ytStreamBuffer", new Uint8Array(await e.data.arrayBuffer()))
}
```

Comment: Do share more of your code.

Comment: You construct and start the `recorder` immediately, but `sourcesMediaStream` isn't fully set up until the `getUserMedia` promise resolves. You need to wait until your `.then` block to set up the recorder. Not sure if more is going on here, since per the other comment there seems to be some code missing.

Comment: @kdau the problem not in the first time starting the recorder but in the second time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparantly I had An old chrome version so it was the wrong version thanks to every one who helped